# Call transitionFadeWithDuration() from CCTransition in Swift

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make this:

```
class GameScene: CCNode{
func exitButtonPressed(){
...
var transition: CCTransition = CCTransition.transitionFadeWithDuration(1,5)
...
}
}
```

But Xcode return "Extra argument in call" error.

The project is get from SpriteBuilder and I make it in a Swift class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a 1 and a 5 when you want to be passing 1.5. Just swap your comma for a decimal point.

```
1,5
```

Should be

```
1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, did simply swapping the comma compile the code? I ask because when attempting to call the method as you did above (changing comma for period) such that:

`var transition: CCTransition = CCTransition.transitionFadeWithDuration(1.5)`

I received an error: ('CCTransition.Type' does not have a member named 'fadeWithDuration').

I had to treat it as an init method and thus call:

```
let transition: CCTransition = CCTransition(fadeWithDuration: 1.5)
```